# How to reinstall the uninstalled system apps (that arent availble on Google Play)

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, system-apps, nokia-x

What if you accidentally deleted some important apps and couldn't install them back because Google Play doesn't have them? For example android system, com.android dun server and com.android.lgsetup wizard (i.e. any prebuilt system apps). And every few seconds this message would appear:

```
Sorry! The process com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

And I cannot even go to the browser or Task Killer because every time I do, it would force quit. How can I reinstall those apps? I think I cleared all data for those but I did not clear the browser and so why can't I open the browser?
Do I really need to send it for repair or can I fix it?

Device: Nokia-X

Answer (score 2):

You need to reflash the OS. First, find the stock ROM for your device: [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/12442) explains how to get started. Then you'll need to consult the manufacturer's instructions for flashing a new ROM, and flash the ROM for your device.

Answer (score 1):

Since you deleted pre-installed apps,  you have to be rooted. There a couple of options, basically involving the same steps.
Most likely for these options to work you'll have to have a custom recovery installed.

Goto one of the forums that caters to your device.

- Download and flash a custom ROM.
- Download and flash a stock ROM or the same ROM.
- Download and extract the files you deleted from the same ROM that is already installed. Then place them in their respective locations.

For flashing a ROM, there should be directions/instructions specifically for your device on the website you downloading from.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Dan Hulme answer is correct and probably the best way to have everything restored.
Another way that could be easier depending on your knowledge is to find stock ROM, extract apps you deleted from your phone and push them back in your phone using adb.
Since you deleted system apps I am assuming that you have root access.